# Is there anyway to synchronously retrieve bitmap from Glide on main thread?

Tags: android, android-glide

I would like to use the awesome Glide cache but not finding a way to synchronously check if an image is available and pull the bitmap if it is. I only see async methods. Am I missing something? I want the bitmap then a byte array, and have no plans to put it in an imageview.   If its in the cache I want to sync obtains its byte array. Can this be done?  I saw this: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/495

But that just deals with setup issue for an imageview not really what I need.

Comment: why would you need Glide to do it synchronously ?

Comment: Ok   public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)  on WebViewClient does not wait around for asynchronous response. @Blackbelt   If you want to hand webview an image from the cache you do it right there and then.